# Permission Denied calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to make [ie7-js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) work with my wordpress installation. After reading about this library it seems like it is a great solution to making my website more compatible with older versions of IE more specifically IE8. It may seem odd to try and still support an old browser like that but I have noticed that several hundred visitors a month are visiting our site using browsers as old as IE6. A majority of our users are elderly and still using Windows XP. Now on to the problem.

I am running a copy of the Windows XP virtual machine with IE8 from [modern.ie](https://modern.ie/en-us) I have followed the instructions on the library code page on how to include the file. I am trying to get the Specific IE9.js file to work. When I access the page in IE8 I get the error

`permission denied: line 850 character 37`

I have tracked it down to the line below:

`for (var i = 0, imported; i < styleSheet.imports.length; i++)`

from this function:

```
function getCSSText(styleSheet, path, media, level) {
      var cssText = "";
      if (!level) {
        media = toSimpleMedia(styleSheet.media);
        level = 0;
      }
      if (media === "none") {
        styleSheet.disabled = true;
        return "";
      }
      if (media === "all" || media === self.media) {
        // IE only allows importing style sheets three levels deep.
        // it will crash if you try to access a level below this
        try {
          var canAcess = !!styleSheet.cssText;
        } catch (exe) {}
        if (level < 3 && canAcess) {
          var hrefs = styleSheet.cssText.match(IMPORTS);
          // loop through imported style sheets
          for (var i = 0, imported; i < styleSheet.imports.length; i++) {
            var imported = styleSheet.imports[i];
            var href = styleSheet._href || styleSheet.href;
            imported._href = hrefs[i].replace(TRIM_IMPORTS, "");
            // call this function recursively to get all imported style sheets
            cssText += getCSSText(imported, getPath(href, path), media, level + 1);
          }
        }
        // retrieve inline style or load an external style sheet
        cssText += encode(styleSheet.href ? loadStyleSheet(styleSheet, path) : styleSheet.owningElement._cssText);
        cssText = parseMedia(cssText, self.media);
      }
      return cssText;
    };
```

Upon researching to see if anyone else has had the same issue I did find [posts](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=59) regarding it but none had solutions to them. I have been trying to sort this out for a few hours now only to be banging my head against the desk. Does anyone have possible solutions or things to check next? I have tried changing file permissions to 777 but that does not seem to work either.

Comment: You probably already figured this much, but it appears to be a permissions problem with accessing certain *.css files. What's the style of your page URL, and the URLs of the stylesheets you've imported? (Not going to click it, but there's a chance some big difference in URLs might cause issues)

Comment: Folder permissions do not directly affect the performance of front-end script, so this makes no sense. Maybe your problem is a Perm "frame" or "url".

Comment: I've noticed some of the URL's in the head are called using the absolute path while others contain an href link like so `href='//example.com/wp-content/themes/vivacity/assets/css/stylesheet.css'` Notice that the `http:` has been ommitted

Comment: I just read an article here that certain versions of IE will download the style sheet twice. I am wondering if this could be causing an issue? I need to try and track down where these css files are getting called in the code to add the protocol. This could take a while.....
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5a-missing-schema-double-download/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I have made them into absolute urls. I have noticed that I have some stylesheets being pulled from google. Not sure if this would affect anything or not.

Comment: @Katana314 I don't know if I have to tag you in a comment for you to see it or not...

Comment: @Yamaha32088 this is the exact problem, what happens is a "safety block" and is required reading about "CORS" to understand. Tell me "getCSSText" is a function of "moderm.ie"​​? Because if it is then this is a bug you should report them in the repository (if any).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `getCSSText` is a function of the ie7-js library linked in the question. Modern.ie is just a virtual machine that you can select an operating system and browser to test things in. How would a guy prevent this safety block? I have added the site to a list of trusted sites.

Comment: as I said this is a "bug", there is no way to prevent a "client-side", I recommend that you host the css in a "CDN" with "CORS" permissions (server-side).

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers have limitations when working with CORS on client-side.

Not quite a "bug" from his javascript and can not be corrected by the client-side.

The best way is to work with [CDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) that have permissions to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

- http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/
- http://support.maxcdn.com/howto/use-cdn-with-webfonts/

Yet still can be difficult, so another alternative would be to put all the CSS on a sub domain your (or your own domain).

Read about CORS:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
- http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Yeah, that was the suspicion I was thinking of in my comment. The idea is basically that an attacker could use stylesheets, and JavaScript access to them, as a method of communication to an outside site (either their own site, accessing one containing data, or the other way around). It's possible IE will allow the stylesheet, but not let you look at it in JS.